# Bonobo Git Server: how do you open complete repository in windows explorer/backup?

Tags: windows, git, server, bonobo

I recently installed Bonobo git server on my workstation. It will work as a git server for me and my colleagues. Using a script, the repositories will be stored on a separate server usinng a .bat file to copy the files regularly. The problem is I don't know where to find the repo files. I selected D:/git_repo as destination for bonobo repositories, but when i go there in explorer, there are only a few files and not the sources (the folders are alos only a few hundreads kbs big).

Do you have any ideea where the complete files are located?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, instead of using a scheduled script to copy the repository files to a separate server, I would on the destination/backup server have a scheduled task that performed a 'git pull' from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed the Repository directory in the Bonobo UI settings ?

If you did, try to restart the IIS service.

If none helps, thenWhat exactly are you copying ? If your repositories are initialy exist, either by a script you execute or by the Bonobo UI, they can be created directly to your D:\Git_Repos as you specify